# preg_match to search a number in a string

Tags: php

I have string

```
$str = http://localhost/tim-yeu-cau/entry/XXX/?sort=5&dir=asc
```

I want to extract number XXX between `entry/` and `/` using `preg_match`

My code does not work.

```
preg_match('/^entry//', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: 1) With `^` You say that the string has to start with `entry` 2) Use a capturing group and `\d+` to capture the number between the slashes 3) Escape your slashes otherwise it will be seen as delimiter for your regex

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
$str = 'http://localhost/tim-yeu-cau/entry/123/?sort=5&dir=asc';

preg_match('/entry\/(\d+)\//', $str, $m);

var_dump($m[1]);
```

**Output**

```
string(3) "123"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = "http://localhost/tim-yeu-cau/entry/1213213/?sort=5&dir=asc";
$from = "entry/";
$to = "/?sort";

echo getStringFrmStrtEnd($str,$from,$to);

function getStringFrmStrtEnd($str,$from,$to)
{
    $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
    return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
}
```